# Wordpress plugin development/ hook after function is executed?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

with my plugin i want to display an image on top of a theme. the highest possibilaty is where some tags are displayed with post_class function. My question is if it's possible to hook right after the function is executed?

Answer (score 0):

as you can see the content of post_class function is echo

```
function post_class( $class = '', $post_id = null ) {
     // Separates classes with a single space, collates classes for post DIV
     echo 'class="' . join( ' ', get_post_class( $class, $post_id ) ) . '"';
}
```

you can see How to use post_class() in an echo as example below:

```
echo '<div ' . post_class() . '>';
```

you can create another filter function and calling post_class in content.
Good Luck!